# How to loop through merged cells and read each one for text

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet called Sheet3 where I merged cells together into big 11 x 6 squares and I lined them up. There are 12 of these blocks that are all 7 cells apart from each other. I defined the name of each of these blocks, "Car_1" through "Car_12". I'm trying to write a block of code where I can create an array with my Car_1 through Car_12 blocks and I can go through each one and determine if there's text written in the block to the right of each, If there is then the ID of that block to the right can be printed in a cell elsewhere on the sheet (there are 12 blocks total so the output could range in cells "C2" to "C13" ) on the contrary, If there was no text written in the block to the right of the one being focused on then no output is given, it would just go to the next block down the line until all the blocks are lopped through. However, whichever block that would be on the end would need a different action taken for it. So when the program would look at that block, it would print "Right End" instead of an ID when there is no block with text at any point down the line after it. This what I have so far, but of course it doesn't work:

```
Sub Code()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TxtRng As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")

Dim Cars(12)
i = 1
For Cars = 1 To 12
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("Car_(i)")) Then

Set TxtRng = ws.Range("C2")
TxtRng.Value = "Yes" 'Car(i) ----> ID
Else
TxtRng.Value = ""    'Blank

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("Car_12")) Then

        Set TxtRng = ws.Range("C13")
        TxtRng.Value = "Right End"

Next i

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In my code, I only focus on what happens when Car_12 is looked at rather than wherever down the line where a block has no block to its right with text.

Comment: Is it necessary to use merged cells? Working with unmerged cells is a lot easier... Anyway, what is the exact issue with the code you've already written? What doesn't it do, which you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yeah I'm limited to using merged cells sadly, and I'm new to VBA so I just need my syntax checked and how to write the code for dealing with the block on the end

Comment: I essentially need to know which block is to the right of each block being looped through:

Comment: Like in cells "B2" through "B13" would have 1 through 12 listed down them, and cells "C2" through "C13" would have the output (what's to the right of each number in cells B2 through B13) it should literally be 1 --> 2, 2 --> 3, etc. unless let's say block Car_3 has no text then Car_4 would be the output when Car_2 is looked at in the loop

Comment: Do you specifically want to use `IsText` - i.e. if there's a number in a block, it will be ignored? Or do you just want to check that the length of the block's value is > 0?

Comment: I'd like for any value in the block to be looked at, so is `IsBlank` a better option @BigBen

Comment: And what if for example - Car 2 is blank and Car 3 is not - would the output be 1-->3, 2-->3 or would you skip 2?

Comment: 2 would be skipped @BigBen so it would be 1 --> 3, 2 -->  , 3 --> 4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the next car by using a nested loop. The code below cycles through cars 1 to 11 in the first `For` loop, checking for the next non-blank car in the nested loop immediately after. Once if finds the next car, it exits the nested loop and writes the index of that car to the relevant row in the range `C2:C13` - here I am using `i` and `Offset`ting from `C1` to get that row.

I found it easiest to construct a second loop to get the "Right End" - just loop from Car 12 backwards and look for the first pair of cars where the last is blank and the second to last is not. Note that if Car 12 is not blank, it is automatically the "Right End."

```
Sub Code()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    ws.Range("C2:C13").ClearContents

    ' First loop to compare a car to the rest after it
    For i = 1 To 11
        For j = i + 1 To 12
            If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & i)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & j)) Then
                ws.Range("C1").Offset(i).Value = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    ' Loop backwards to find "Right End"
    For k = 12 To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_12")) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(12).Value = "Right End"
            Exit For
        ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & k)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & k - 1)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(k - 1).Value = "Right End"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```

**Screenshots** - definitely simplified from your file but demonstrate the concept.

*Possibility 1*
[image]

*Possibility 2*
[image]